# KnowledgeableUser does not support search

Tags: sobject, sosl

Using [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm) I did the following Query:

> FIND {*name*} in NAME FIELDS  Returning [KnowledgeableUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgeableuser.htm)(ID)

Console returns the following:

> entity type KnowledgeableUser does not support search

It looks like this Object is not query-able, is there any way to change this as the object is not available from the setup menu since i think it is set by default to searchable=false ?

tried open execute anonymous windows as well:

> List> searchList = [FIND 'name' in NAME FIELDS Returning KnowledgeableUser(ID)]

[image]

Comment: Did you also try querying in `Execute Anonymous Window`, i remember some SOSL queries are not supported by Developer console

Comment: yes i did, same result

Comment: You are filtering on single field, why not use SOQL?

Comment: in the example i provided, yes, i only search for one single object and field, however, my use case involves text search on multiple objects and fields

Comment: Ah ok, Seems like the object does not supports SOSL.

Comment: Yes, if you take a look at the Standard Objects, for **Knowledgeableuser**there are three option :  **describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()** .... there is not **search()**.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgeableuser.htm?search_text=KnowledgeableUser

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo would you mind posting your comment as an answer =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the **Standard Objects**, for **Knowledgeableuser** there are three options : `describeSObjects()`, `query()`, `retrieve()` .

There is not **search()** method available.

[Link to SFDC Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgeableuser.htm?search_text=KnowledgeableUser)